# getting cannot allocate vector of size 8.4 Gb error in glm in r

Tags: r, memory, memory-management, glm

I am trying to run the following model to understand the importance of interaction between various sectors. I have excluded the term for individual factors separately but still i am running into memory problem. The code is follows:

`count_med_op3 <- glm(Count_OP ~ nationality_final +  age_group + Gender + class_room_type2 + nationality_final * age_group + nationality_final * Gender + nationality_final * class_room_type2 + age_group * Gender + age_group * class_room_type2 + Gender * class_room_type2 + offset(log(exposure_2015_2016)), data= med,family='poisson')`

Error: cannot allocate vector of size 8.4 Gb

Please help as i am getting this error in the first stage and i also have to run:

`dredge(count_med_op3,extra = c("AIC","R^2"))`

P.S. i am using R 64bit on a 32GB ram server

Comment: How big is your dataset?

Comment: 3,349,500 rows with only relevant columns being pulled using sql query into r (i.e. nationality_final, age_group, Gender, class_room_type2, exposure_2015_2016, Count_OP)

Comment: Sounds like you don't have enough memory. Not sure that this will work, but you could look into the `biglm` package which has a `bigglm` function.

Comment: I am now using `bigglm` but i keep getting this error `Error in coef.bigqr(object$qr) : 
NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 3)`. I tried changing `chunksize` but no luck.